# Constant on path-connected components implies constant

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Suppose $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is connected. Let $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function. Prove that if $f$ is constant on the path-connected components of $X$, then $f$ is constant on $X$. I was able to prove this in the case where $X$ has a finite number of path-connected components. In fact, we can proceed by induction. Starting with a path-connected component, its closure must intersect the closure of another path-connected component; by continuity the constant on these must agree. I have no idea how to handle the general case, any hint is appreciated. The case where $f$ is uniformly continuous (or Holder) is of interest too. In that case, we can reduce the problem to a compact $X$, if that is of help. I wonder if the cardinality of path-connected components of a (compact) connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be countable. If that was the case, maybe an induction could be useful. Thanks!

Comment: If the number of path components is cardinality less than the reals you are immediately done, since the image being a connected metric space either has cardinality of at least the reals, or is a singleton. [I am not sure at all whether that's the right proof strategy though]

Comment: Note that $(\{0\}\times ([0,1]\backslash \mathbb Q)) \cup \{(x,\sin(\frac{1}{x}))\mid x>0\}$ has path components of cardinality equal to the reals.

Comment: Why do you want to prove this?  It is not true.

Comment: For instance, $X$ can be compact, connected but contain no path-connected subsets of cardinality $>1$.

Comment: @EricWofsey thanks for you comment. Why is it false?

Comment: @MW thanks for your example! This is not a compact counter-example, but its intersting to see that in the non-compact case the cardinality of the path-connected components can be the continuum.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks for the example. In that case, X has an uncountable number of path-connected components, right? Very intersting. Could you comment on the existence of such $X$?

Comment: This is also not compact but is a counterexample, since if you remove one point it becomes totally disconnected, which immediately implies path components are singletons: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster-Kuratowski_fan (I would also be interested in the compact counterexample)

Comment: @MW very intersting example. Thanks!

Comment: Take for instance the pseudo-arc. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! Intersting example. This shows that cardinality is not a useful tool for the problem. What do you think about the problem stated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One example where the claim that you are trying to prove is false is given by the [pseudo-arc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) $A$, which is a nondegenerate planar continuum (i.e. a compact connected subset of the plane containing more than one point). The  pseudo-arc has a number of remarkable properties, in particular:

(a) It is homeomorphic to any of its nondegenerate subcontinua.

(b) it is indecomposable, i.e. it cannot be represented as a union of two proper subcontinua.

From these two properties, it is easy to conclude that every continuous map $[0,1]\to A$ has to be constant. In particular, every path-connected subset of $A$ is a singleton. It is also clear that $A$ admits a nonconstant continuous function, e.g. the restriction of a coordinate function.

Edit. For the sake of completeness, here is a proof (one of many) that every continuous map $f: I=[0,1]\to A$ is constant. Suppose that there exists a nonconstant map $f$. Pick two distinct points $x, y\in f(I)$; (after renaming $x, y$ if necessary) there exists a subinterval $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$ such that $f(a)=x, f(b)=y$ and $f^{-1}(\{x,y\})\cap [a,b]=\{a,b\}$. The image $f([a,b])$ is connected, compact, hence, is a nondegenerate continuum, hence, is homeomorphic to $A$. Thus, by restricting $f$ to $[a,b]$, we reduce to the case $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Since $f^{-1}(\{x,y\})=\{0,1\}$, the subcontinua $f([0, 0.5])$ and $f([0.5, 1])$ in $A$ are both proper, nondegenerate and their union is $A$. This contradicts the fact that $A$ is indecomposable.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks!